# How to retrieve value from a public JS script?

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

Im doing a research on Crypto API and want to get the current price of a coin. I used [TradingView](https://www.tradingview.com/widget/symbol-info/) widget to display all the chart and data on my webpage. So now I only want to retrieve the current price from the widget, is it possible? [image]

What've tried:

This widget is in `iframe`, so i tried to called  `document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.body.innerText;` But unfortunately, it showed `Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8080" from accessing a cross-origin frame`. Does anyone know ways to retrieve these value from the JS script?

For the full code I cant paste it here because stackoverflow blocked it, can go to this [page](https://www.tradingview.com/widget/symbol-info/) to generate widget

Comment: You can not access the contents of an iframe, that were loaded from a different origin, using client-side JavaScript.

Comment: @CBroe Is there any hacky ways to reach my intention?

Comment: If you're willing to write a PHP script, as implied by your tags, this might be possible - the term to search for is "web scraping" (as in "to scrape", not "to scrap"). Note that the attitude of the site hosting the widget will range from not caring if they break your script to actively trying to stop you using the content this way. Ideally, you would look for an API which is actually designed to be used in this way.

Comment: @IMSoP Yes, API is the best way to do it but all the free API are very slow.

Comment: @IMSoP Since there are no data exposed on the front end code itself, does web scraping able to scrape the data?

Comment: Anything that shows up in your browser has been sent to your computer somehow; ultimately, web scraping is just doing the same job as a browser, and interpreting what gets sent. That can get incredibly complex, to the point that it's not worth the effort, but it's always possible *in principle*. As for free APIs being slow: processing and bandwidth cost money, as does programming and in some cases access to data; so if you're not paying towards those costs, don't expect someone else to be paying lots on your behalf.

Answer (score 0):

This is the tradingview api https://www.tradingview.com/rest-api-spec/#operation/getQuotes.
You can authenticate using username and password. If you want access to the data you will need to use the api or go with some kind of web crawling approach. The data in iframes as well as the cookies on that page are protected from you for security reasons so you wont be able to get a hold of them in that way.